# Simple Wordpress back button in PHP - wrong place of displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to create a back button for one of my sites. I want my button visible only on post pages, at the bottom of content. Using Internet :) I created something like that:

```
function wpb_after_post_content($content){
    if (is_single()) {
        $content .= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
          echo "<div class=\"back-button\"> <p class=\"back-button-txt\"><a href='$backbuttonurl' onclick=\"if (document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.host) !== -1) { history.go(-1); return false; } else { window.location.href = ' . get_site_url(); . '; }\">&#171; BACK</a></p></div>";
    }
        return $content;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_after_post_content' );
```

Problem is that my button is showing at the top of content and at the bottom is a text of link to previous site(?). I am a begginer and would like you to look at this code and tell me why isn't it working the way I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `echo` with `$content .= "<div class="...`.

You should just return data from filter not echo.